# What do I do when I can't find the source of this chapter of a book so I can cite it APA style?

Tags: citations, citation-style

I have found part of a book in .pdf file format and it contains some information I would like to use in my study. I'm trying to cite the book APA style, but I can't find any information on it whatsoever. I've spent ages searching around for any information I could find from within the PDF, but failed as only that specific PDF keeps popping up in the results. I can't make a citation if I don't even know the title of the book or the author.

My citation currently looks like this, with "Onbekend" meaning unknown and "z.j." meaning no year:

> Onbekend. (z.j.). Onbekend. Opgehaald van
>   http://wps.pearsoned.co.uk/wps/media/objects/10977/11240737/Web%20chapters/Chapter%2012_WEB.pdf

Which is unacceptable.

The part of the book in question is [here](http://wps.pearsoned.co.uk/wps/media/objects/10977/11240737/Web%20chapters/Chapter%2012_WEB.pdf).

What should I do now?

Comment: A 10-second google books search using a random sentence from the .pdf file suggests that it might be [**Modern Database Management**](https://books.google.com/books?id=F7MWrgEACAAJ) [Pearson Education, 2015] by Jeffrey A. Hoffer and Ramesh Venkataraman and Heikki Topi.

Comment: Search more or Ask an expert.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Whenever I search for any random sentence, even ones such as the one in the intro text: "distributed database, decentralized
database, location transparency, local autonomy", Google Books tells me there is no result and once again states the .PDF. How did you manage to create results?

Comment: Maybe I got lucky, but I copied the top line on p. 12-5 -- *A significant trade-off in designing a distributed database environment is whether* -- and did [this phrase search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22A+significant+trade-off+in+designing+a+distributed+database+environment+is+whether%22&tbm=bks).

Comment: That is incredibly strange! If I click your phrase search, it says "No books found" and then lists only the PDF from my question!

Comment: I searched for the first line or so in the introduction. Another route is it's from wps.pearsoned.co.uk I.e. Pearson education, it's got a chapter title and number you can search for too.

Comment: I checked the link AFTER I made the comment, and it worked, and it works now, a few minutes later. I got one book result that says no preview is available, but it does allow me to get information about the book (which I posted a link to earlier). I'm in the U.S.A. -- I wonder if that makes a difference?

Comment: I guess it makes a difference, check this out: http://imgur.com/a/XX52h (Dave's link)

Comment: Dave's links seem to work for me, in the UK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book your looking for seems to be:

Modern Database Management

By Jeffrey A. Hoffer, Fred R. McFadden, Mary B. Prescott

https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Modern_Database_Management.html?id=cYfDQgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y&hl=en

Comment: Also see: https://www.pearsonhighered.com/product/Hoffer-Modern-Database-Management-10th-Edition/9780136088394.html

Comment: Hoffer, J., Venkataraman, R., & Topi, H. (2015). Modern database management. Prentice Hall Press.